# LINQ Errors out on Any() if results NULL

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query and in some cases it returns no values. So I am using the `Any()` to check  for that so I can handle the code accordingly. But when I use `Any()` or `Count()` I get the following error:

```
{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: g"}
```

This is the code I am using:

```
var cQuery = (from a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact")
where ((((EntityReference)a["accountid"]).Id.Equals(new Guid(p.AccountGuid))) &&
((a["firstname"].Equals(p.FirstName) && a["lastname"].Equals(p.LastName) && a["address1_stateorprovince"].Equals(p.State)) || (a["emailaddress1"].Equals(p.Email))))
    select new
        {
            ContactId = !a.Contains("contactid") ? string.Empty : a["contactid"],
        FirstName = !a.Contains("firstname") ? string.Empty : a["firstname"],
        LastName = !a.Contains("lastname") ? string.Empty : a["lastname"],
        State = !a.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : a["address1_stateorprovince"],
        Email = !a.Contains("emailaddress1") ? string.Empty : a["emailaddress1"]
    }).DefaultIfEmpty();

if (cQuery.ToList().Any())
    {
        // Do something if I get results
    } else {
      // Something else if no results
    }
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Seems like it should work for me. In the case that it is error out. It would be returning no results so I would want it to skip over the whats in the `if`. But in other cases there will be results. Thanks!

UPDATE:

I know the code is ugly. Sorry.

It looks like the problem is the:

```
where ((((EntityReference)a["accountid"]).Id.Equals(new Guid(p.AccountGuid)))
```

It looks like the where is getting a NULL. How would I go about handling that so the error doesn't pop up?

Comment: I can't see how that would possible cause a problem - it's after `ToList()`, after all. Can you produce a shorter query example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Perhaps one with less parenthesis porn...  Though the casting is likely where your error is.

Comment: wow - this shouts "refactor me ... PLEASE" ;) - honestly I cannot even find a parameter named "g" - you sure you gave us the part that throws the exception (all of the queries?)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Agreed. My eyes glazed over when I looked at that.

Comment: err... what's the `DefaultIfEmpty()` for if you check afterwards?

Comment: Check gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact") because the 'g' might be in there.

Comment: This looks like a migrated Java code :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter name "g" is the name of the parameter in the `new Guid(string g)` constructor.

Therefore, I suspect your root cause is actually that `P.AccountGuid` is null in certain circumstances.

Comment: Yes, this must be, I checked with ILSpy and the constructor raises this error when g is null

Comment: Good call. The folowing simple statement also gives the same exception: `new Guid((string)null);`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go for the ToList function instead?

```
            var cQuery = (from a in gServiceContext.CreateQuery("contact")
                      where ((((EntityReference)a["accountid"]).Id.Equals(new Guid(p.AccountGuid))) &&
                      ((a["firstname"].Equals(p.FirstName) && a["lastname"].Equals(p.LastName) && a["address1_stateorprovince"].Equals(p.State)) 
                      || (a["emailaddress1"].Equals(p.Email))))
                      select new
                      {
                          ContactId = !a.Contains("contactid") ? string.Empty : a["contactid"],
                          FirstName = !a.Contains("firstname") ? string.Empty : a["firstname"],
                          LastName = !a.Contains("lastname") ? string.Empty : a["lastname"],
                          State = !a.Contains("address1_stateorprovince") ? string.Empty : a["address1_stateorprovince"],
                          Email = !a.Contains("emailaddress1") ? string.Empty : a["emailaddress1"]
                      }).ToList();

        if (cQuery.Count > 0)
        {
            // Do something if I get results
        }
        else
        {
            // Something else if no results
        }
```